# Mixed Content - SSL

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ssl, mixed-content

So I have one of my script tag addresses referring to a ui-Bootstrap template.
the address is a non ssl address (http). The thing is i have now enabled ssl encryption on my SPA and chrome for example blocks me from retrieving data from that source.

When i change it from http:// to https:// then the functionality (in this case a date time picker) depending on that source stops working..

Is there some way of granting permission for that script tag and address/source code-side, or maybe even bypassing it for that specific source?

Best Wishes and thanks in advance - John!

Comment: No what you are trying to do is not possible. Just download the source and host it yourself. *Which is something you should be doing either way imo*

Comment: Ok thanks for that fast response.

Comment: See if your framework is hosted at https://cdnjs.com/